# Why the notation of pointer type starts with asterisk?

Tags: c, go, pointers

Passing pointers to functions I constantly get confused for a second. If we create an integer value variable, like `var a int` (in Go it would be `0`) to get its address (a pointer to it) we would use *ampersand notation*, `pA := &a`. To get a value behind the pointer we use *asterisk notation*: `b := *pA`. Makes sense, no problem. But why the creators of the language (and it's not only Go) chose the notation of the pointer type to be `*int` instead of `&int` (i.e. `func test(i *int) {}` accepts an address to an integer as an argument). `*` is used to get value, `&` to get the address. `*int` reads to me like *a value (of) int*, `&int` (which doesn't really exist in the language) reads like *an address (of) int*.

That's a question about the history behind the notation of the pointer types, why is it asterisk instead of ampersand, what is the logic behind it?

Comment: There are those who argue that `int *x` declares that the dereferenced type of `x` is `int` (although that argument doesn't really work for `void*`).

Comment: The `*` and `&` operators are largely inverses of each other.  For instance, `*&x` in C is equivalent to `x` (assuming `&x` is allowed).  The `&` operator takes a step back, giving the address of the object, while the `*` operator takes a step forward, giving the contents of the object.  They are very much opposites of each other.

Comment: Yes, I can see how they are the opposite operations, but that is indeed my point. Why notation for the pointer was chosen with the opposite operation, while direct exists at the same time (* vs &).

Answer (score 5):

From DMR's [The Development Of the C Language](http://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html):

> For each object of such a composed type, there was already a way to mention the underlying object: index the array, call the function, use the indirection operator on the pointer. Analogical reasoning led to a declaration syntax for names mirroring that of the expression syntax in which the names typically appear. Thus,

> ```
> int i, *pi, **ppi;
> ```

> declare an integer, a pointer to an integer, a pointer to a pointer to an integer. The syntax of these declarations reflects the observation that `i`, `*pi`, and `**ppi` all yield an int type when used in an expression.

So, they used the asterisk for pointer variable declarations because that is what's used for dereferencing said pointers (And that came from the earlier B language).